# Window Replacement Contract Question

Tags: blinds, contractors

I ordered 16 Window replacement to a company. I paid the advance 4 weeks back. After few days one of their tech tells me that they would install window in 4 to 10 weeks and I would need to take off all the blinds and put them back myself. If I do not take care of blinds either crew can refuse to do the job or they would charge you additional $20/30 per window to take blinds off. They never mentioned anything about blinds in any earlier discussions. I checked with my neighbor who replaced his windows few months back and for him replacement crew removed and put back blinds with no questions asked. When I talk to the sales guys they tell me that this is a standard practice in industry and everyone understands that blinds removal is home owner's job and hence it was never discussed. I am a new home owner and seek guidance here. With kids in home there is no way I can do the job for 16 Windows in a day or two plus one window needs a 40ft ladder too. I am trying to understand what is the best practice in industry? Is blind removal part of the job or it is owner's responsibility?

Comment: Read your contract, it should lay out your responsibilities and theirs.  One reason to ask friends and neighbours for recommendations of companies.  This is not really a good question for this site.

Comment: Thank you crip659 for your response. I have read the fine print of contract and it does not say anything about blinds. Is it possible to at least know what is the standard practice for blinds? Do replacement company normally takes care of it or it is always owner's responsibility?

Comment: Between you and your neighbour I would say 50/50, some do, some don't.  Imagine it might be a matter of maybe damage caused to the blinds that some companies do not want to deal with, or it slows down the work.

Comment: Standard practice is some owners remove the blinds and some companies do it.

Comment: you mean blinds inside the house?  Some are attached to windows themselves and I wouldn't expect a company to do that for me.  What blinds are attached outside the window so you need a ladder?

Comment: vote to close. this is a legal question. feel free to edit to ask perhaps how to remove the blinds, but sorry, as it stands this is IMO not a DIY question

Comment: You have blinds on a window that is 40' above the floor? Is this a window at the top of an open stairwell in a 4 story house? Holy cow, that's a long way up for _interior_ blinds!

Answer (score 1):

If your contract doesn't mention anything about blinds, then the company isn't going to be responsible to remove them and then re-install them. If you had hired painters to paint the room, they wouldn't be expected to remove the blinds and remove the furniture.  I've removed many blinds for people getting hurricane windows because those windows can be bulkier and interfere with the blinds. I've also see windows replaced without removing the blinds. It depends on the situation and there are no standard practices. Removing most blinds are fairly easy and just means turning a few brackets that will probably remain so reinstalling will be easy. Maybe you'll want to negotiate the window that needs the 40 ft ladder.